# Get current memory usage of WKWebView?

Tags: ios, xcode, posix, wkwebview

In the application I am currently developing I have a requirement to watch the memory usage of the WKWebView. I cannot figure out how to do this. As WKWebView runs seperate from the main app, so getting diagnostics on the main app do not reflect the WKWebView.

Has anyone done this before?

It seems as though on iOS 9 you simply cannot look at other processes running. So that option is out. However I am still not sure, is WKWebview even another process? I notice when launching a new WKWebView, it creates new threads under mach_task_self. So that implies to me the WKWebView is not actually a seperate process, but is in the same process / mach task as the main app. But it's memory is in a different address space.

Is it possible to somehow grab the seperate memory space of the WkWebview through the low level mach and posix methods?

Or is there any other way to get the memory usage of the WkWebView?

Comment: We were very excited about wkwebview because of the decrease in memory usage until we realized that the memory was just being hidden... our app would crash randomly without warning because of high memory usage which we couldn't effectively monitor

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21956 Have you seen this? I think it answers at least part of your question.

Answer (score 12):

In Xcode, choose "Product" and then select "Profile", after the compilation，it will open Instruments.

Select **Activity Monitor** and click **Choose**.

[image]

Click the red circle at the top left to start profiling.

[image]

Try to find the process named as "com.apple.WebKit", the column of "Real Mem" is what you wanted.

[image]